# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 40,Token in error = First]

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing C# accessing SQL Server. But I am getting an error as:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 40,Token in error = First]

```
private void CustomerAdded(Customer c)
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    try
    {                               
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        
        query = string.Format("INSERT INTO CustomerRecord(CustomerId, First Name, Surname, PhoneNumber, City,Country, Account Manager) VALUES ({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')",c.CustomerId,c.FirstName,c.Surname,c.PhoneNumber,c.City,c.Country,c.AccountManager);
        
        SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
        
        rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this is were the error say line 162
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
    GetCustomers();
    bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *white-space* in your column name(s) you need to use square brackets.Use `[First Name]` instead of `First Name` and `[Account Manager]` instead of `Account Manager`.If  you are inserting a value to all of your columns then you don't need to specify column names.

Also you should consider using [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to prevent `SQL Injection` attacks.

Comment: Thank you so so much  Selma22, is workinggggggggggggggg after putting [First Name] instead of First Name and [Account Manager].